# How can we share a backend MS Access 2016 on One Drive

Tags: database, ms-access, backend

We operate a small retail business with three retail shops. Each shop has it's own PC running Windows 10 and Office 2016 (we subscribe to Office 365 Home edition). We have created a customer ordering database in Access 2016 and now wish all three shops to have access to this (add records etc) We have tried splitting the database and putting the backend on OneDrive and providing the other two with the front end. Whilst this works perfectly for the shop that split the database it is not available to the other two. Can this be done on OneDrive or should we be looking at something like SharePoint?

Comment: It is not advisable to run MS Access outside a local area networked PC environment unless dedicated servers such as SharePoint and Office365. So, internet folders like OneDrive, GoogleDrive, Dropbox, even thumb drives may result in unintended consequences. Use these only for file transfer or storage.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work. *OneDrive* is a file syncing service, not a file share.

Move (upsize) the backend to a server engine like *SQL Server* (Express) or *Azure SQL*, which you can access from your front end application via the internet.